# Does youtube api play function trigger a view count?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I know that embedding a video with autoplay will NOT increment video count.

My question is, playing the video from javascript, with the youtube api, does it trigger incrementing video count?

Comment: If they made it so iframed videos with autoplay doesn't increase video count so that people doesn't abuse it, I think it will be even more restricted with the player api, as you would be able to abuse it even further. Having said that, I have no idea. Why don't you try it? Just upload a new video private, get the ID and play it on a youtube API.

Comment: @Tebb My thoughts exactly. Will test it.

Comment: you are probably aware of it but YT takes hours to update the viewcount of the videos, specially if the video is not popular, which will be the case. And please, answer this question once you reach a conclusion.

Comment: yeah, probably in a couple of hours I should have relevant results.

Comment: so the test confirms Tim's answer. It could of been really stupid to work. You could just call play from onYouTubePlayerReady :)

Comment: @Aleix did it have time to update yet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Playbacks started with the javascript API do not count, nor do any other views which are initiated by software (auto playing, iframing the page, playlist player, chromeless player api, etc).

YouTube Developer Relations response: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/youtube-api-gdata/7SsbvOJMWL0/rBCBqnFaxRgJ

Comment: can you tell, "iframe API" is similar to "Javascrip API"? (i mean, if in Iframe API,  views counts or not)

Comment: The API you use to control the iframe is a javascript api, which has the same limitations.

Answer (score 3):

If you autoplay the video it won't count but you can have it count as long as you don't autoplay and let the user interacts with a 'Play' button.

---

> - Playback controls and player settings : player.playVideo():Void plays the currently cued/loaded video.  Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

```
    https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
```

> - Playback locations report: Embedded players on other websites: This shows how many people viewed your video when it was embedded on another website, like a blog. Click on the link to drill down to a breakdown of views across the various sites that have embedded your video.

```
    https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714546?hl=en&ref_topic=3029003
```

Comment: Still says the same as of today